# Earth's core must be producing light, where is that light energy going?

Tags: thermodynamics, earth, geophysics

Earth core is about 5000°C hot. It must be producing light but no one can see it. So where is that light energy going? It isn't escaping to space for sure.

Comment: Well, yes, the Earth radiates into space. But the surface is cooler than the core. And you may have noticed (particularly if you go caving) that the ground is pretty good at absorbing visible light.

Comment: There is nothing special about the Earth. The inside of a piece of metal held in fire is not visible even though is may reach 1000 degrees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the electromagnetic energy emitted by the core (including light waves) is repeatedly absorbed and re-emitted at longer and longer wavelengths by the thousands of miles of rock between the core and the surface. We cannot see the core for the same reason that we cannot see the sun shining up through the Earth at night - there is too much rock in the way.

Eventually this energy *is* escaping to space (via the Earth’s atmosphere) but by the time it reaches the surface it is in the form of long wavelength infrared radiation, not visible light.